# RStudio attach row index to points on graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, scatter-plot

I have a map with points on it, each representing a location. I want to attach the row index so that it appears in the centre of each point. My code to render the map:

```
p <- ggmap(basemap)
p + geom_point(data=Data, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), size=3)
```

Comment: Add `geom_text()` with the `label` argument set to the variable you want.

Comment: @Phil What would the proper syntax be?

`p + geom_point(data=Data, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), size=3) + geom_text(aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), label=Data$Freq) `
This doesn't seem to work

Comment: The label argument goes within aes().